# OracleParameterCollection.Add(string, type, string, size, string)

Tags: c#, oracle, parameters, sql-insert

I am using C# and Oracle in a WinForms project. I am receiving the error:

> ORA-01400 cannot insert null into (string) when using "InsertCommand.Parameters.Add".

The problem is the parameters `(":ID", ":NOME", ":OBSERVACAO", ":NUMERO", ":ENDERECO")` are not receiving the values from the "srcColumn" `("ID", "NOME", "OBSERVACAO", "NUMERO", "ENDERECO")` argument of the method "Add". What am I doing wrong?

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ConsultaGRID();
    }

    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=xxx; User ID=xxx; Password=xxx;");
    DataTable tabela = new DataTable();
    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();

    private void ConsultaGRID()
    {
        while (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open) { conn.Open(); }
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select ID, NOME, OBSERVACAO, NUMERO, ENDERECO from CADASTRO_FONES order by ID", conn);

        da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(tabela);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = tabela;

    }

    private void dataGridView1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F6)//Inserir
        {
            GetInsert();
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F10)//Salvar
        {
            GetSave();
        }
    }

    private void GetInsert()
    {
        tabela.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 1].Cells[0];
    }

    private void GetSave()
    {
        try
        {
            while (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open) { conn.Open(); }                
            da.InsertCommand = new OracleCommand("insert into CADASTRO_FONES (NOME, ID, OBSERVACAO, NUMERO, ENDERECO) values (:NOME ,:ID ,:OBSERVACAO ,:NUMERO ,:ENDERECO)", conn);                

            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(":ID", OracleType.Number, 22, "ID");
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(":NOME", OracleType.VarChar, 70, "NOME");
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(":OBSERVACAO", OracleType.VarChar, 70, "OBSERVACAO");
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(":NUMERO", OracleType.VarChar, 20, "NUMERO");
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(":ENDERECO", OracleType.VarChar, 70, "ENDERECO");

            da.Update(tabela);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

I change the "GetSave()" function to code below and still not working:

```
private void GetSave()
    {
        try
        {
            while (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open) { conn.Open(); }                
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("insert into CADASTRO_FONES (NOME, ID, OBSERVACAO, NUMERO, ENDERECO) values (:NOME ,:ID ,:OBSERVACAO ,:NUMERO ,:ENDERECO)", conn);                

            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("ID", OracleType.Number, 22, "ID");
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("NOME", OracleType.VarChar, 70, "NOME");
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("OBSERVACAO", OracleType.VarChar, 70, "OBSERVACAO");
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("NUMERO", OracleType.VarChar, 20, "NUMERO");
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("ENDERECO", OracleType.VarChar, 70, "ENDERECO");

            da.InsertCommand = cmd;

            da.Update(tabela);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of the colons in the Parameters.Add:

```
 da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(":ID", OracleType.Number, 22, "ID");
```

should be

```
 da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("ID", OracleType.Number, 22, "ID");
```

The colon is used in the actual SQL string to denote a bind parameter.  When you create the parameter, just name without the colon.

See example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledataadapter.insertcommand(v=vs.110).aspx)